# Is it possible to eval code as a transient group description?

Tags: elisp-macros, eval, backquote, transient-library, transients

I want to customize the title of a `transient` group based on the value of some variable, `my--current-section`. The following doesn't work

```lisp
(transient-define-prefix my--prefix ()
  "Sample docstring"
  `[,(format "Manage (current section: %s)" my--current-section)
   ("c" "Configure" my--configure)
   ("o" "Open" my--open)
   ("s" "Submit" my--submit)
  ])
```

IIUC because `transient-define-prefix` is a macro, and it doesn't eval its arguments. Neither using `(eval ...)` works. Is this possible?

---

**EDIT:** What I want is to have the title of the transient group contain a string. To do this, the usual (?) way is to provide the title as the first element of the vector passed to `transient-define-prefix`, say

```lisp
(transient-define-prefix my--prefix ()
  "Sample docstring"
  `["Group title"
   ("c" "Configure" my--configure)
   ("o" "Open" my--open)
   ("s" "Submit" my--submit)
  ])
```

If I try to use, in place of the string, some elisp code, this doesn't get evaluated, and instead interpreted as a generic transient option. Therefore

```lisp
(transient-define-prefix my--prefix ()
  "Sample docstring"
  [,(format "Manage (current section: %s)" my--current-section)
   ("c" "Configure" my--configure)
   ("o" "Open" my--open)
   ("s" "Submit" my--submit)
  ])
```

interprets the `,` as the character to use as key, so I get the error `(error "No key for ,")`.

Using `eval` like this

```lisp
(transient-define-prefix my--prefix ()
  "Sample docstring"
  [(eval
    (format "Manage (current section: %s)" my--current-section))
   ("c" "Configure" my--configure)
   ("o" "Open" my--open)
   ("s" "Submit" my--submit)
  ])
```

similarly, triggers `(error "No key for eval")`.

Using backquoting

```lisp
(transient-define-prefix my--prefix ()
  "Sample docstring"
  `[,(format "Manage (current section: %s)" my--current-section)
   ("c" "Configure" my--configure)
   ("o" "Open" my--open)
   ("s" "Submit" my--submit)
  ])
```

instead returns `nil`, and doesn't install the function.

Comment: Please say what you mean by "doesn't work", show what you tried with `eval`, etc. E.g., provide a recipe to reproduce the problem, saying what you see and what you expected to see instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works:

```lisp
(setq my--current-section "XXX")

(defun my--set-section ()
  (format "Manage (current section: %s)" my--current-section))

(transient-define-prefix my--prefix ()
  "Sample docstring"
  [:description my--set-section
    ("c" "Configure" (lambda () (interactive) nil))
    ("o" "Open" (lambda () (interactive) nil))
    ("s" "Submit" (lambda () (interactive) nil))
    ])
```

Or like this:

```lisp
(setq my--current-section "Manage (current section: XXX)")

(transient-define-prefix my--prefix ()
  "Sample docstring"
  [ my--current-section
   ("c" "Configure" (lambda () (interactive) nil))
   ("o" "Open" (lambda () (interactive) nil))
   ("s" "Submit" (lambda () (interactive) nil))
   ])
```